# nx.read_gexf not returning graph

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, networkx, gephi

I am trying to import an interactive graph from Gephi into a Jupyter notebook but when I try to read it in by pathname as instructed in the guidebook, it doesn't show.

Attempted code:

```
nx.read_gexf("/Users/User/Desktop/ICL/NA/W1/network.gexf")
```

Returning:

> networkx.classes.graph.Graph at 0x16cd619b0

I've attempted setting it to a variable/summarizing it, returning it, and trying the rgexf library. I've only used nx.write_gexf in the past and had no issues like this.

Comment: What do you mean by _"interactive graph"_. I 've been using `networkx` but haven't had issues if the graph is static